# Autocomplete JqueryUI COMBOBOX + Select all text

Tags: jquery, combobox, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete combobox , and its all working great.

Visit http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox .

The issue is , I want make this combobox such that upon clicking in the box the text inside get selected, so that the user can start searching for next without clearing old text.

solution I tried for testing on $(document).ready...

```
        //clear each option if its selected
        $('#<%=combobox.ClientID  %> option').each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('selected')
        });

        //set the first option as selected
        $('#<%=combobox.ClientID  %> option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');

        //set the text of the input field to the text of the first option
        $('#<%=combobox.ClientID %> ').parent().children('input.ui-autocomplete-input').val(' ');
```

dint work ...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$.select()](http://api.jquery.com/select/) is what you need. In your particular case do this when you build the autocomplete box:

```
 $('#autocompletebox').autocomplete({...blablabla... }).focus(function() { $(this).find('input').select(); $(this).select(); });
```